# python dictionary keys order

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a code in python, that creates a dictionary with some keys and values. But, I need to have the values ordered in same order as they was added. So code

```
def getdataready():
    data = {}
    data["cputemp"] = str(getcputemp())
    data["cas"] = str(datetime.datetime.now()).replace(" ", "%20")
    data["fan"] = str(fanstate())
    data["pstemp"] = str(getPStemp())
    #there are some more keys added
    return data
```

declares the dictionary and returns it. But when I run the code, the returned dictionary is ordered without any rules (pstemp, cas, cputemp, venkovniteplota, fan, pokojovatelota)
How can I order they in the order of declaration(cputemp, cas, fan, pstemp,...)?
I need it, because in this order, the dictionary is sended to webserver ( http://parman.moxo.cz/index.php?page=info using wget and dictionary is converted into url and given to PHP as values in $GET) and there is displayed in the same order as it was received and I'd like to have it in this order 
Thanks.

Comment: Also, use snake case for the method name `def get_data_ready()`

Comment: @Kasra i get 404, maybe wrong link?

Comment: To control the order of items in a dictionary, you can use an `OrderedDict` from the `collections` module. It exactly preserves the original insertion order of data when iterating. :
`from collections import OrderedDict
data= OrderedDict()` read more https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict). It provides the functionality you asked for and keeps the keys in the order they were added.

Comment: Thanks you all, only needed to import collections.
(for some reason, I can't accept answer right now, so wait)